# How to show view actions in Django REST Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to make a spreadsheet of the endpoints in our api and the methods that can be used, and I'm trying to use django's `show_urls` management command as a base.

My question is: is there a way to get the allowed methods on a view from the view class itself?

Comment: You should probably be using DRF's OpenAPI schema generation features for this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/

Comment: Yeah swagger seems to miss a bunch of urls for me so I'm trying to do it myself, I was thinking maybe I could use the options function or something? Just some way of showing the available methods